# My django app font from Digital Ocean spaces are not working

Tags: css, django, digital-ocean, django-staticfiles

I have a django app on a live server, the static files are hosted on Digital Ocean spaces. The static files are working well but the fonts are not. I thought probably it was because the font files are linked to the /static/ folder so I changed the `@font-face src: url()` parameter to the digital ocean spaces cdn link for the font files but its not still working. I even embedded the `@font-face` rule in the html template and connected the font files with the django static files template url but its still not working. Though the font is working on my loacalhost.

```
{% load static %}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <style type="text/css">

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'TT Norms Pro';
            src: url(' {% static 'user/fonts/TTNormsPro-Bold.eot' %} ');
            src: local('TT Norms Pro Bold'), local('TTNormsPro-Bold'),
                url('{% static 'user/fonts/TTNormsPro-Bold.eot?#iefix' %} ') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('{% static 'user/fonts/TTNormsPro-Bold.woff2' %}') format('woff2'),
                url('{% static 'user/fonts/TTNormsPro-Bold.ttf' %}') format('truetype');
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'TT Norms Pro';
            src: url('{% static 'user/fonts/TTNormsPro-Regular.eot' %}');
            src: local('TT Norms Pro Regular'), local('TTNormsPro-Regular'),
                url('{% static 'user/fonts/TTNormsPro-Regular.eot?#iefix' %}') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('{% static 'user/fonts/TTNormsPro-Regular.woff2' %}') format('woff2'),
                url('{% static 'user/fonts/TTNormsPro-Regular.woff' %}') format('woff'),
                url('{% static 'user/fonts/TTNormsPro-Regular.ttf' %}') format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }


    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'user/libs/css/bootstrap.min.css' %} ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'user/libs/fontawesome/css/all.min.css' %} ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'user/libs/css/flatpickr.min.css' %} ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'user/libs/css/animate.css' %} ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'user/default-styles.css' %} ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'user/styles.css' %} ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'user/media-queries.css' %} ">


    <script src=" {% static 'user/libs/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src=" {% static 'user/libs/js/popper.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src=" {% static 'user/libs/js/bootstrap.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src=" {% static 'user/libs/js/list.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src=" {% static 'user/libs/js/sweetalert2@9.js' %} "></script>
    <script src=" {% static 'user/libs/js/flatpickr.js' %} "></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/88095687d9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Open dev tools in your browser and look for a CORS error. This is the most common cause.

Comment: @Daniel-Morell yeah I see CORS errors for all the font files. It says (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). That mean I'll have to add the CORS configuration on DO spaces yeah?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working now. I just needed to add the CORS configuration.

Comment: Maybe you could post an answer to your own question to explain what you've done to fix this, because it might be helpful to future visitors!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this problem occurred because my website did not have cross-site access to the font files so it is not allowed to use them. To solve this problem, I went to the CORS configuration on my Digital Ocean Spaces Account and added my domain name to the "Origin" field, I also set the "Allowed Methods" to GET. Then the fonts started working on my website. For more in formation about this visit [Digital Ocean Spaces CORS configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/configure-cors/)

Comment: Hi Cyberposh, did you set any allowed headers? I'm facing the same issue right now for hours !! :(

Comment: Well, you can also set allowed headers in your django app with the [djangocorsheaders](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)  module. This will solve the problem.